# When c > 0 Log(n) = O(n)? Not sure why it isn't O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, logging, complexity-theory

In my homework, the question asks to determine the asymptotic complexity of n^.99999*log(n). I figured that it would be closer to O( n log n) but the answer key suggests that when c > 0, log n = O(n). I'm not quite sure why that is, could someone provide an explanation?

Comment: Where is c defined?  What bearing does it have on n?

Comment: *c* is typically used to denote the hidden constant in big-O notation; *f(n)* = O(*g(n)*) if there exists constants *c* and *N* such that *f(n)* < *c* *g(n)* for all *n* > *N*.

Answer (score 3):

It's also true that lg *n* = O( *n<sup>k</sup>* ) (in fact, it is o(*n<sup>k</sup>*); did the hint actually say that, perhaps?) for *any* constant *k*, not just 1. Now consider *k*=0.00001. Then *n*<sup>0.99999</sup> lg *n* = O(*n*<sup>0.99999</sup> *n*<sup>0.00001</sup> ) = O(*n*). Note that this bound is not tight, since I could choose an even smaller *k*, so it's perfectly fine to say that *n*<sup>0.99999</sup> lg *n* is O(*n*<sup>0.99999</sup> lg *n*), just as we say *n* lg *n* is O(*n* lg *n*).

Comment: lg n = O( n^k ) for any constant k - log n = O(n^2)??

Comment: Yes. You are confusing O(n^2) with Θ(n^2). Big-O merely provides an upper bound, but says nothing about the lower bound. Theta provides both upper *and* lower bounds.